# Schedule of buses going from Antalya to Kumluka / Kas and back

Tags: turkey, antalya

Can anyone give me an advice about schedule of buses going from Antalya to Kumluka / Kas and back? Especially in December (if it is different in off-season)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Kumluca, [based on this website](http://www.antalyaulasim.com.tr/icerik/kumluca-otogar), there are a lot of bus firms that you can use from Antalya (or to Antalya). Mostly used ones are [Kamil Koç](https://www.kamilkoc.com.tr/), [Metro Turizm](https://www.metroturizm.com.tr/en/) and [Pamukkale Turizm](https://www.pamukkale.com.tr/). I choose one of these if I were you.

For Kaş, [based on this website](https://onlinebilet.com/otogar-kas-otogari), there are Metro Turizm, [Ulusoy Turizm](https://www.ulusoy.com.tr/), Kamil Koç and Pamukkale Turizm which I suggest as well.

You can check their websites and see the bus schedules. These schedules usually *won't* change based on seasons by the way.

Comment: But what city should I search for? There is no Antalya in the selection?!? Anamur, Ankarayol, but nothing else starting with An...

Comment: @IvanGerasimenko On Metro Turizm page, both `Antalya <--> Kumluca` and `Antalya <--> Kaş` options are available as far as I can see. But not for others weirdly. You can still call their call centers (phone numbers which you can take their websites) to get a "better" information for your vacation schedules.

Comment: Antalya is not placed in alphabetic order. It goes first like Istanbul... Thanks

Comment: @IvanGerasimenko Yeah, some websites do that. They list mostly used city names on top of the list instead of alphabetic order. In Turkey, Istanbul, Izmır and Ankara can be examples for this situation.